# On click on document body not working on ios devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I have created a side navigation bar in one of my websites. On body click, I need to hide the navigation bar for that I have used below code-

```
    jQuery(document.body).on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        try {
            closeNav();
        } catch (ex) {

        }
    });
```

But in IOS devices, body click is not working. For this I searched for its solution. Many people suggested to put `touchstart` event along with click event. I tried it but on scrolling also that event is firing.
I have tried `touch` event also but its not working.

I tried following approach also-

```
    jQuery(document).on('touchstart', function () {
        documentClick = true;
    });

    jQuery(document).on('touchmove', function () {
        documentClick = false;
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click touchend', function (event) {
        if (event.type == "click") documentClick = true;
        if (documentClick) {
            try {
                closeNav();
            } catch (ex) {

            }
        }
    });
```

I tried setting these events on `document.body` also. but it didn't work.
So I put these events on `document`. But these events are now working on whole document. I only want to fire click event on body.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your  `jQuery(document)` and  `jQuery(document.body)` with `jQuery("body")` and It should work try this :)

Comment: @Sonali I have added bymistake capital J , now I have edited just check